# python scipy minimize ValueError

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to use scipy minimize and running into a ValueError error that just I can't seem to figure out.

I have an objective function f as defined below, which takes two inputs.  If I define the two inputs with random numbers, and call the function, it seems to evaluate just fine.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize

sigma = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 7), columns=list('ABCDEFG'))
x0 = np.random.randn(7)

def f(x, sigma):
    result = 0.0
    sigmaX = sigma.dot(x)

    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            result = result + (x[i] * sigmaX[i] - x[j]*sigmaX[j])**2

    return result


In [387]: f(x0, sigma)
Out[387]: 371.67951578983951
```

But when I try to use minimize, I get a ValueError:

```
In [389]: minimize(f, x0, args=(sigma))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 7
```

I can't figure out whether minimize is upset about the shape/size of x0 or sigma.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Eric

Comment: Try `args=(sigma,)`.  That is make sure you give `args` a tuple.  Without the `,` the `()` does nothing.

Comment: I would kiss you if I could.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Copied from my comment, so it can be marked as closed

Try args=(sigma,). That is make sure you give args a tuple. Without the , the () does nothing.